# Why can't I install pip for a local Python 2.7.12 installation?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, ssl

#### Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a VMWare virtual machine.

I am trying to set up a local python 2.7.12 environment using `make` in order to create a virtual environment for an application I'm working on. However, for some reason, when I go to install `pip` via python's `ensurepip` command, I am met with an error: `Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS`

#### Here are the steps I take in the terminal:

```
# Install necessary packages
#
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install curl make g++ \
                     zip zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
                     bzip2 libbz2-dev \
                     libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev ncurses-doc \
                     libssl-dev \
                     uuid-dev \
                     sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev \
                     libapr1 libapr1-dev libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dev \
                     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
                     haproxy

# Configure environment
#
WW_PREFIX=~/company/application
export WW_PREFIX

# Update PATH (.profile)
#
PATH="${WW_PREFIX}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Python
#
curl -O "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/Python-2.7.12.tgz"
tar xvfz Python-2.7.12.tgz
cd Python-2.7.12
./configure "--prefix=${WW_PREFIX}" --with-threads --with-ssl --with-zlib
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -rf Python-2.7.12
rm Python-2.7.12.tgz

# Test that it works
#
"${WW_PREFIX}/bin/python" -V
```

The next step would be to call this:

```
sudo -H "${WW_PREFIX}/bin/python" -m ensurepip
sudo -H "${WW_PREFIX}/bin/pip" install --upgrade pip
```

But when I get to the `ensurepip` line, I get the error

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user/webworks/clouddrafts/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS
```

I've been all over the place trying to solve this. Many other solutions suggest that `libssl-dev` is needed for this particular error, but I have that installed as we see in my `apt-get` list. I have also tried the `get-pip.py` method with a similar failure. I want to say the SSL library just isn't being found for any of these attempts, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you didn't have openssl-devel at the time of installing python, pip 8.1.1 won't install. After installing openssl-devel, reinstall python. This time it should install pip just fine.

Comment: You're right, `openssl-devel` needs to be installed. On a hunt for how to do that, I found out that for my version of Ubuntu, I needed to install `libssl1.0-dev` instead of `libssl-dev`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this, I needed to properly install `openssl-dev`. For Ubuntu 18.04, and my case, this was solved by installing `libssl1.0-dev` instead of `libssl-dev`.

`sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev`